# Need to smooth an image using matrix - Calculate sum of cells and compute average

Tags: java, matrix

I have matrix each cell contain number I need to calculate the cell and its neighbor cells and come out with an average of that cells.

Look at the code that I wrote.

```
public Matrix imageFilterAverage() {
        for (int i=0; i < _array.length;i++)
            for (int j=0; i < _array[i].length;j++){
                _array[i][j] = (_array[i][j] + _array[i][j+1] + _array[i+1][j] + _array[i+1][j+1]) / 4;
            }

        return this;
    }
```

My code return error on index issue when j+1 reach 3 it is out of bound because the cells are 0 1 2.

So for example, if I have a matrix like this

```
10 5 7 3
50 3 2 1
60 2 5 2
```

The results matrix should be like this.

```
17 12 3 3
21 16 2 3
28 20 2 2
```

I have posted the images one matrix source and matrix results [image: source matrix]

[image: Results matrix]

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: you wrote what you need to do, but that is not a question??

Comment: How do I resolve the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that your for loops are going too far, or you are not checking your bounds.  You have stated this yourself - when j+1 is 3, it fails because the cells are 0, 1, 2.  You must stop j from going up to 2, or else you must skip adding the cell j+1 when it is out of bounds.

Comment: I don't get how you calculate those results. Can you please explain for example how you get from 230 to 98 for your array element at [1][3]?

Comment: You calculate all the cells that surrounding that cell including itself then divide by the number of cells to get the average and then you put that average back in that cell.

Comment: `if (i+1 < array.length) { sum += array[i+1][j]; count += 1;} if (j+1 < array[i].length) { sum += array[i][j+1]; count += 1;) ... newArray[i][j] = sum / count;`  you have to create corresponding variables and maybe reset their values (you need a new array to not overwrite the original until all calculation is done) ((sure this can be optimized, but I doubt that is a problem (now)))

Comment: I found a solution
https://xp-dev.com/sc/201086/HEAD/%2FMatrixAssignment%2Fsrc%2FMatrix.java

Comment: Thank you Carlos thank you Jamie and thank you Eritrean :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
    /**
         * Takes the given array and transforms each slot in the array as an average of the slots around it.
         * @return an array with each where each slot in the array is "blurred" by the slots around it.
         */
        public Matrix imageFilterAverage() {
            int avgArray[][] = new int[_twoDiPicture.length][];
            int numOfCellsAround = 0;
            int cellsSum = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < _twoDiPicture.length; y++) {
                avgArray[y] = new int[_twoDiPicture[y].length];
                for (int x = 0; x < _twoDiPicture[y].length; x++) {
                    numOfCellsAround = 0;
                    cellsSum = 0;
                    numOfCellsAround += cellsAround(y, x);
                    cellsSum += cellsSum(y, x);
                    avgArray[y][x] = cellsSum / numOfCellsAround;
                }
            }

            return new Matrix(avgArray);
        }

/* a private method that  deals with index out of bound exceptions. */
    private boolean isInBounds(int y, int x) {
        return y < _twoDiPicture.length && y >= 0 && x < _twoDiPicture[y].length  && x >= 0;
    }

    /* A private methods that uses "isInBounds" to find how many cells are surrounding the target array. */
    private int cellsAround(int y, int x) {
        int cells = 1;

        if (isInBounds(y + 1, x)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y - 1, x)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y, x + 1)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y, x - 1)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y - 1, x + 1)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y - 1, x - 1)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y + 1, x - 1)) {
            cells++;
        }
        if (isInBounds(y + 1, x + 1)) {
            cells++;
        }

        return cells;
    }


    /*A private method that returns the sum of all the adjacent cells around target cell. */
    private int cellsSum(int y, int x) {
        int sum = _twoDiPicture[y][x];

        if (isInBounds(y + 1, x)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y + 1][x];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y - 1, x)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y - 1][x];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y, x + 1)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y][x + 1];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y, x - 1)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y][x - 1];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y - 1, x + 1)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y - 1][x + 1];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y - 1, x - 1)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y - 1][x - 1];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y + 1, x - 1)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y + 1][x - 1];
        }
        if (isInBounds(y + 1, x + 1)) {
            sum += _twoDiPicture[y + 1][x + 1];
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an ugly solution which can be improved:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {{10, 5, 7, 3},
                      {50, 3, 2, 1},
                      {60, 2, 5, 2}};

    int[][] average = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< matrix[0].length; j++){
            int sum = 0;
            int div =  ((i==0 && j ==0) || 
                        (i==0 && j == matrix[0].length-1) || 
                        (i== matrix.length-1 && j ==0)|| 
                        (i==  matrix.length-1 && j == matrix[0].length-1)) ? 4 : 
                       ((i==0 && j > 0) || 
                        (i>0 && j == 0) || 
                        (i== matrix.length-1 && j >0)|| 
                        (i>  0 && j == matrix[0].length-1))? 6 : 9;

            for(int k = Math.max(i-1, 0); k <= Math.min(i+1, matrix.length-1); k++){
                for(int t = Math.max(j-1, 0); t <= Math.min(j+1, matrix[0].length-1); t++){
                    sum += matrix[k][t];
                }
            }
            average[i][j] = sum / div;
        }
    }
    for(int[] r:average){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
    }
}
```